# How best to save python code?

Tags: python

I am learning with an online interpreter and would like to save bits of code in my Google drive. Is there a good way to do this so I can easily copy and paste my work back into a webpage. If there is a better way to save it that isn't in the cloud I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: Are you using a pc or some kind of android device?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is with a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), for example [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) are popular choices for python users.

You can then host your code for free on [github](https://github.com/) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), amongst other services.

Comment: I'm learning on my chromebook so this might be the best option. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you download or have a text editor ( something like Sublime text ) you can paste it into that, put in the syntax you are using so your code is highlighted. Save it via that. However if you want something online, use github or for simplicity dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use Google Drive, just save your .py files and drop them into Google Drive. Then you can edit using the ShiftEdit extension (https://shiftedit.net/). But Github Gists or a similar product is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a VCS, you could use `git` with GitLab. Just head over to http://www.gitlab.com and create your personal account, and have unlimited private repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Something like gist.github.com or jsfiddle.net whould work, though they're both "cloudish".  You could always create a local directory and use git or hg or some other distributed version control system to manage your code.  That would be a good learning experience too.